# NSAttributedString - get font attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I need to get info about my attributed string but can't figure out how. I'm getting this dictionary:

```
2013-11-04 18:06:10.628 App[1895:60b] {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.3 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x17d8d4c0> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt";
    NSUnderline = 0;
}
```

It is easy to check the underline with:

```
[attrs objectForKey:@"NSUnderline"]
```

But how to get info about font like the font-style, font-weight etc.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you getting that dictionary from?  It doesn't strike me as an attributed string.

Comment: It looks like it might be the output for an attributesAtIndex: method

Comment: Yes, I get it from enumerateAttributesInRange method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get the font from:

```
UIFont *font = attrs[NSFontAttributeName];
```

The issue is determining whether it is bold or not. There is no property for that. The only option is to look at the `fontName` of the font and see if contains "Bold" or some other similar term. Not all bold fonts have "Bold" in the name.

The same issue applies for determining of the font is italic or note. You have to look at the `fontName` and look for things like "Italic" or "Oblique".

Comment: Even if I'm getting the dictionary above? I mean there is a property font-weight and font-style which is what I want. I just don't know an easy way to read it. So the informations are there the problem is how to read them.

Comment: I believe @adam is interested in using font.description to determine various font properties (font-weight, font-size etc). Font description is not meant for this, it may break in future.

Comment: There is no dictionary for the font. That is the output of the `UIFont` description.

Comment: In the end I used this answer. It is easier to accomplish and as you say more reliable. Thanks

Comment: OK but if you are only supporting iOS 7 (or later) then using `UIFontDescriptor` will be much easier and much more reliable. I wasn't aware of this new feature in iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

`UIFont` has fontDescriptor starting **iOS7** so you can try out that..

```
// Returns a font descriptor which describes the font.
    - (UIFontDescriptor *)fontDescriptor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Usage:

```
// To get font size from attributed string's attributes
UIFont *font = attributes[NSFontAttributeName];
UIFontDescriptor *fontProperties = font.fontDescriptor;
NSNumber *sizeNumber = fontProperties.fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute];
NSLog(@"%@, FONTSIZE = %f",fontProperties.fontAttributes, [sizeNumber floatValue]);
```

Similar to `UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute` you can find other traits like `UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute`, `UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute` etc as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I succesfully tried to do this: UIFontDescriptor *desc = [attrs objectForKey:@"NSFont"]; but when I want to log the fontAttributes dictionary it fails with unrecognized selector sent to instance. How to get these information from descriptor?

Comment: @adam You have to get the `UIFont` first like I showed in my answer. Then get the font descriptor as shown in this answer.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, your answer helped me complete mine. I have edited my answer above to reflect the same.

Comment: @Ashok what does 'attributes' mean? I am not able to get the attributes of NSAttributedString

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to get info about your attributed string in this example that checks if a substring of the attributedText of a label is BOLD.

```
-(BOOL)isLabelFontBold:(UILabel*)label forSubstring:(NSString*)substring
{
    NSString* completeString = label.text;
    NSRange boldRange = [completeString rangeOfString:substring];
    return [self isLabelFontBold:label forRange:boldRange];
}

-(BOOL)isLabelFontBold:(UILabel*)label forRange:(NSRange)range
{
    NSAttributedString * attributedLabelText = label.attributedText;

    __block BOOL isRangeBold = NO;

    [attributedLabelText enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:range options:0 usingBlock:^(UIFont *font, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (font) {
            if ([self isFontBold:font]){
                isRangeBold = YES;
            }
        }
    }];

    return isRangeBold;
}

-(BOOL)isFontBold:(UIFont*)font
{
    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor;
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    BOOL isBold = (fontDescriptorSymbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0;
    return isBold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A update running iOS 10.0 swift 3.0 and the code [Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654016/ashok) solution has become something along these lines.

```
let fontDescription = focus.font?.fontDescriptor
let fontAttributes = fontDescription!.fontAttributes[kCTFontNameAttribute as String]!
```