# iOS - UITableViewCell make text bold

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode5

I have a string:

```
NSString *userInfo = @"James Johnson @james";
```

What i want to do is bold `James Johnson` and keep `@james` normal font.

So what I have tried is using `NSAttributedString` but somewhere I'm doing something wrong in order to complete the process.

This is what I have tried:

```
NSString *user = @"James Johnson @james";

UIFont *fontLight = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];
UIFont *fontBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:userInfo];

//TESTING WITH RANDOM PARTS OF THE STRIN
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:fontLight range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:fontBold range:NSMakeRange(3, 5)]; 

NSString *str = [string string];

cell.textLabel.text = str;
```

Is there a way I can make this work even if I'm on the wrong direction?

## What's not working

For some reason, the characters from range 0 - 3 is not being a light font...instead the entire `cell.textLabel.text` is bold somehow and is not font size 14 which i had specified in the UIFont.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: You have to set `attributedText` to cell label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last part of it is wrong. You must create your `NSAttributedString` and finally trash the formatting by using

```
NSString *str = [string string];
```

As `NSString` doesn't know anything about formatting you have to use the `NSAttributedString` to assign it to the cell's `textLabel`:

```
cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;
```

Comment: I tried that but got an error: `[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.` I think it has to do with the `addAttribute - values` portion of the code...

Comment: This is because you set the color instead of the font. So please replace `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` with `NSFontAttributeName`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FlorianMielke. Was doing same. Saved a day.

Answer (score 3):

You should set `attributedString` to `attributed` text

Comment these lines

```
//NSString *str = [string string];
//cell.textLabel.text = str;
```

And write this

```
cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;//Set NSMutableAttributedString only not NSString
```

Comment: I tried this but i got this error: `[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I think it has to do with the `addAttribute` - `values` portion of the code...

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773129/nsattributedstring-get-font-attributes

Answer (score 0):

UILabel has a property attributedText. You should be assigning this property with your attributed string and not use text property.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in you code as follows :

1. You will require to report all the characters with in the NSMutableAttributedString, so specify them with in the range, while adding an attribute.
2. Provide correct attribute name, else you will have an exception here, in this case you should use "NSFontAttribteName" in place of "NSForegroundColorAttributeName".

```bash
NSString *user = @"James Johnson @james";

UIFont *fontLight = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];
UIFont *fontBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:user];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontLight range:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontBold range:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];


cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;
```