# How to format certain words of a cell's text label

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, fonts

I have a xamarin iOS project where I am displaying a cell with x lines of text. I currently define my cells like so:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("cells");
        ...
        cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = "Bold: " + info1 + "Bold: " + info2;

        ...
    }
```

Which displays the cell like:

```
   +----------------------+
   |Bold: Testing         |
   |Bold: Testing2        |
   +----------------------+
```

I want to be able to turn just the `Bold` text to the bold font and keep the other info in normal text font. Is this possible given my current approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "YOUR FIRST TEXT STRING", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
let anotherString = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR SECOND TEXT STRING", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()])
attributedText.appendAttributedString(anotherString)
cell.TextLabel.AttributedText = attributedText
```

You can change your font size as well as color.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to post my own answer in xamarin style just for posterity sake, but your answer is correct!

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your use of `UITableViewCell`, I came accross the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853433/ios-uitableviewcell-make-text-bold) - it looks like you might be able to manipulate the text via `NSAttributedString`

Comment: This is the right answer. `UITextView`, `UITextField`, and `UILabel` all have an `attributedText` property. You can build an attributed string where the words you want are in bold and then assign that string too the field's `attributedText` property

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Santos for the answer! Here is what I ended up using to get it to work for me in `xamarin/c#`:

```
var attributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString("Bold:", font: UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(17f));
var infoText = new NSAttributedString(info);
var bold2 = new NSAttributedString("\nBold: ", font: UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(17f));
var infoText2 = new NSAttributedString(info2);

attributedText.Append(infoText);
attributedText.Append(bold2);
attributedText.Append(infoText2);
cell.TextLabel.AttributedText = attributedText;
```